# EMR run out of memory after many iterations and not clear the cache even I terminate my process

Tags: caching, apache-spark, memory, memory-leaks, emr

I'm running a spark job on my EMR on AWS

```
Master:m3.xlarge
Core:r3.xlarge * 4
```

It is a long running process which will loop the same job in each hour. In each iteration, it will load about 600M data from S3, doing some basic operations like map, groupby, reduce, collect, and finally write data to RDS. I use dataframe and dataset to do all my jobs, and use ganglia to watch the memory usage.

And at the start of each iteration, I will call `spark.catalog.clearCache()` to make sure that all my cached datasets are unpersisted. I check out the value of `spark.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs.keys.size` and get 0 in each start of my iteration.

However, my memory usage is still growing slowly, below is the memory usage screenshot after running my process two days

[image: after running my process about two days]

Some weird thing is that after the memory usage touch the upper limit, my "use" memory start to go down and my "cached" memory keep going larger, like below:

[image]

And finally it run out of memory after about 3-4 days

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f91f9d03000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

Moreover, after the process is terminated, the "cached" memory is still persisted like below:[image]

Since what I do is the same in each iteration and it can start from zero without any data comes from the pervious iterations. How can I really "clean" my memory usage on my machines in each iteration? Thanks!

Comment: What kind a job are you running on ? Something like ALS or PIC ?

Comment: Just read json files and do some aggregate and count and save the result to DB

Comment: You were referring to iterations. What kind of iterations are you talking about ?

Comment: Since I will do the same job each hour, so I just write a loop to do this, if the job is done before one hour, I just let it sleep for a while. Like this

``` loop() { doMyJob; SleepIfNeeded; loop} ```

Comment: If you're running an infinite loop inside of 1 job, this could be a problem.  I would suggest controlling the run schedule (every hour or whatever) from an external process, which could be a simple as cron or more involved like Oozie (I'm sure others exist also).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014486/tool-ways-to-schedule-amazons-elastic-mapreduce-jobs) for more as well.

Comment: Yeh, I know I can use some other controlling process to do it, but the job is to update my dashboard which need instantly report some important changes. It just that it will search for data from a new S3 bucket each hour, so I can clear all the data used and cached before since I don't need them anymore, but I can't find a way to do this.